# java define list of classes in other package and folder

Tags: java, object, package

I have a class in package Enemies and in folder Enemies. the class is called Fly and I need to define a list of classes that are in package cards and in folder cards that this enemy can use. Here are my four classes:

```
import Cards.*;
import Enemies.*;
public class AttackCards    //main class
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        Fly fly = new Enemies.Fly();
        fly.setThis(new AttackCards());
        fly.useCard();
    }
}

package Enemies;
public class Fly extends Enemy
{
   public Card[] enemyCards = new Card[super.cardBridge.Swoop()]; 
   //need to define list of cards able to use
}

package Enemies;
public class Enemy
{
    public Object cardBridge;
    public void setThis(Object ac)
    {
        cardBridge = ac;
    }
}

package Cards;
public class Swoop extends Card     //need list of similar classes
{
    public int damage = 8;
    public void useCard(Object enemy, Object player)
    {
        ememy.health-=damage;
    }
}
```

I have tried giving enemy an attack card class to access the cards package. I have tried creating an blank alternate class in another package which was supposed to be a bridge to the cards package. I have tried putting my main AttackCards class into its own package. How would I be able to define a list of extended card classes in another package and folder?

Comment: Do you want to get a list of all classes in a package without givin a list explicitly? Something that is called a package scan?

Comment: No. I want to be able to define a list of card classes The enemy class can use.